# how to render select dropdown in view page using php code using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My problem is I want to view the select dropdown in page views using php code. Here's my code below
my controller code

example in image rendering to view page

```
$grid->column_orderby(  "Image"
                                ,"<img src=\"uploads/banners/<#br_filename#>\" height=\"60\" alt=\"\" />"
                                ,"bt_filename");
```

I want the line of code to be the same in this way

```
 $grid = new DataGrid("", "banner_rotating");
 $grid->column("Select", "<select name='banner'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select>");
```

and my views page code is this way

```
<?=$output?>
```

and when I see in the views page. I have noticed that the select dropdown is not rendering properly on a page.
Can someone help me how to figured this thing out? TIA

Comment: Do it is controller as $this->data['select_test'] = '"<select name='banner'><option value='1'>1</option></select>'; , pass $this->data to your view then simply echo $select_test

Comment: but how to do it into this one?
 $grid->column("Select", "<select name='banner'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select>")

Comment: In what way is it not rendering properly on the page?

Comment: here see this screenshot link
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f34wr4je6

Comment: I'm assuming that it's meant to only be one row and instead of the option if meant to actually be a select dropdown. Also what is DataGrid, and can you provide a link to it's documentation or download?

Comment: have you seen the screenshot?

Comment: hmmmm since im only fixing in the site dont know too about data grid

Comment: Yes, I saw the screenshot. Either way, without knowing more about dataGrid, I doubt I'll be able to help you. The only thing I can think of is it's a formatting issue. Have a look at using codeigniter's Form helper `form_dropdown()` which will help with any formatting issues (if it is that).

Comment: theyre not using the form_dropdown in CI they are using on theyre own. tsk. Which is very easy if using the CI form_dropdown